# What is /var/log/sysstat/PS?

Tags: 15.10

I am aware that is is probably some kind of data collected by `sysstat`, but - do I need it? One of my servers has 100000 files (10Gb) in there. Is it safe to remove them?

Answer (score 1):

have you `sar`installed? This might be collecting stats on your system storing them in the directory described. please review [this guide](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/03/sar-examples/) to see what might write the log files. Before deleting them I would compress all the files and move them out of `/var/log/sysstat/PS`.